# Run jQuery animation continuously throughout entire website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm running an infinite loop of a color changing background on my website using the jQuery timers plugin (plugins.jquery.com/project/timers):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').everyTime(1,function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#000000" }, 20000).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 20000);
    });
});
```

Now, if you're in "home", and you click a link, it takes you to the appropriate page and it **restarts the animation**. The thing is, I'd like the animation not to restart and to be **continuous throughout the whole site**.

Is there any way to do it?

Can you run a script that doesn't stop and restart every time you go to a differente page, as long as you stay in the same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you run a script that doesn't stop
>   and restart every time you go to a
>   differente page, as long as you stay
>   in the same domain?

No.

> Is there any way to do it?

I suppose you could keep track of the current color in a cookie.  When the animation restarts, check the cookie first.  I'm not a fan of the idea personally but it would work.

If you want it to be completely seamless - you'll need to load every new page of content with AJAX *a la* Facebook, but that's an awful lot of work to serve an animated background.

Comment: +1, the only way to make it really truly seamless would be to stay on the same page and load the new content around the animation.

Edit: learned2spell

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do an AJAX post in your animation loop to a script that saves the current animation status into a session variable for the user. Upon a page load, start the animation from the point indicated in the session variable.